# How to call a method with dynamic dispatch (when method is part of a Module), in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, module, dynamic-binding

In Ruby language, I have to call dynamically a method that belong to a Module, having method name as a stored string (say: `"ModuleName::Submodule:methodName"`)

Let's consider this case:

```
module Dialogs    
  def paperino(param)
    puts "paperino. param: #{param}"
  end
end
```

How can I do .call( "parametro") in run-time ?

I explain better:

In case the method is part of a class I know how to do: 
I Instantiate the class (from the string and I call the method object):

```
class Dialogo
  def pluto(param)
    puts "pluto. param: #{param}"
  end
end

class_name = "Dialogo"
# create class symbol from a string
class_symbol = Kernel.const_get(class_name)

# return a new instance
class_instance =  class_symbol.new

# Instantiating a method object
method_object = class_instance.method(:pluto)

# call the method in run time:
method_object.call "parametro_pluto"
```

And the simpler situation of a method without an explicit class

```
def pippo(param)
  puts "pippo. param: #{param}"
end

method_object = Kernel.method(:pippo)
method_object.call "parametro"
```

But what is the syntax to call dynamically a method that is part of a Module?

In the following example:

```
module Dialogs    
  def paperino(param)
    puts "paperino. param: #{param}"
  end
end
```

the method I wish to call is "Dialogs::paperino"

BTW, I don't want to use neither send() or eval(), but just a call().

thanks
giorgio

Comment: Such a method is not meant to be called. Either include the module somewhere or look at http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/module_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. Methods defined in that way on a Module are not meant to be accessed directly.

```
Dialogs.paperino('a')
NoMethodError: undefined method `paperino' for Dialogs:Module
```

You could define it on `Dialogs` using `self`

```
def self.paperino(param)
```

And then you will be able to access it with `method`

```
Dialogs.method(:paperino)
```

If you need to define it as `def paperino(param)` here is a way you could access the method.

```
method = (Object.new.extend(Dialogs)).method(:paperino)
method.call('foo')
```

This defines a new object and then extends that object with the module `Dialogs`. Then you can get the method.

Comment: Thx! Your answer is clear. I often have trouble with module in Ruby (also for variable scope, :-) ).